# RegEx for matching square bracketed words with no parenthesis following

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown, regex-greedy

I'd like to extend the syntax of Markdown with a simple pre-processing option.

When the text contains some words in squared brackets, but no parenthesis follows it:

`Example text with [some reference] to show.`

I'd like to extend it so that it becomes a self-referencing link:

`Example text with [some reference](some-reference.html) to show.`

Creating the result itself is something I can do on my own, but I have no idea, how can I match *exactly only these* expressions:

```
A word [and more] in the text.                    // this matches
A word [and more](stackoverflow.com) in the text. // this doesn't
```

Comment: @shadoe2020 both seems to work the way I intended to, thank you very much!

Comment: Would you mind if I post as an answer and you can select it since it worked for you?

Comment: Of course I don't, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

`\[([^\[\]]*)\](?!\([^()]*\))`

https://regex101.com/r/64unOk/1

Answer (score 2):

`\[(.*?)\]` for your first, and for your 2nd `\]\((.*?)\)`